# License to include in closed source Android App using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I am developing a closed source android app that uses Firebase (and Firebase requires Google Play Services).

In the firebase [FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/) it says:

> What open source notices should I include in my app?
>
> > On Android use, the [getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(android.content.Context)) method to retrieve the text of licenses to display in your application.
> >
> > On iOS, the Firebase pod contains a NOTICES file which includes the relevant entries.

Is that only for open source software or also for closed source software?
Additionally that getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo() function takes like 10 seconds and loads more than half a megabyte of text. It's ridiculous. Is that really the correct license text to display?

I checked multiple other commercial projects, I never found a license THAT long. Do they just ignore it and hope no one sues?
What I always found was something like "This app contains source code from the Google Open Source Project...[apache stuff]". Would that part be enough? Is there an alternative way to this strange getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo() function? It's almost unusable and the user has to wait a long time for the license to show.

I also checked some of googles own projects that are public on Github. They never used getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo in those projects.

Any recommendations on how what and how to display?

Comment: Interestingly, `getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo` is now removed in Play Services 11.2.0, and the FAQ you linked to removed that quote.

Comment: @manouti You are right. From the official docs: "This method was deprecated. This license information is displayed in Settings > Google > Open Source on any device running Google Play services. Applications do not need to display this license text, and this method will be removed in a future version of Google Play services." https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil

Answer (score 0):

In some applications the `getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo()` function is only called when the user tap the "extra" or "more" button from the credit panel; that often shows a text similar to "This app contains source code from the ...".

Regarding Firebase, as it states "should" and not "must", you are not obliged to do that, even if you should do it to as sign of acknowledgment and gratitude to the hard work of made by people working at the projects you use (thus appreciate).

Comment: [Ah, I sent the comment too soon]

Comment: Ok, you are right, they say that you "should".
But normally licenses are a must not a can. Even so, it seems most don't include the Firebase License in their app. That is why I am asking. So maybe you are right?

Just for reference, I find it perfectly fine to acknowledge the work of others, unless it has a negative impact on the user.
(Googles strange function has a very negative impact).
Also I know that the license is normally hidden, that is what I meant when writing about that I researched what other apps did. They did have a license, just not the full 0.6MB Text provided by google.